# Code to print data of a name, price and its pages by using arrays

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
  char name[3];
  float price[3];
  int i,page[3];

  printf("enter the name price and book\n");

  for(i=0;i<3;i++){

   scanf("%s",name[i]);
   printf("enter character:\n");
     }
   for(i=0;i<3;i++) {
   scanf("%f",&price[i]);
    printf("enter floating point number:\n");
     }
   for(i=0;i<3;i++) {
   scanf("%d",&page[i]);
   printf("enter digit:\n");
     }
   printf("\n");
   for(i=0;i<3;i++) {
   printf("%s\n",name[i]);
     }
   for(i=0;i<3;i++) {
   printf("%f\n",&price[3]);
     }
   for(i=0;i<3;i++){
   printf("%d\n",&page[i]);
     }
    
   return 0;

}
```

When I was trying this code, I thought this was quite simple to do but I realized, there is something which I am missing in the code. The main problem with this code is it is not scanning the values of `price` and `pages`. I don't understand where I am mistaken.

So, please correct my code so that it will print the values of name price and pages.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues in your code. First and foremost, the `%s` specifier (for both the `scanf` and `printf` functions) expects a *string* argument (that is, a `nul`-terminated **array** of `char` for `printf` or an array sufficiently large to hold the input characters *plus* that terminator, for `scanf`); however, you are attempting to read (and print) a **single** `char` value in each of the relevant `for` loops.

To fix this, use the `%c` format specifier, instead of `%s`. However, when you use this, the newline character that is generated when you press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key will be left in the input buffer, [and that will be read as the actual `char` input](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5240807/10871073) on the next iteration of the first `for` loop. To clear any such newline (or, indeed other whitespace) from the input before the real input, add a space in the format string before the `%c`. Also, when using this, you will need to pass the *address* of each `name` element: `scanf(" %c", &name[i]);`.

Further, the `printf` function takes the actual values of the variables to be output, rather than their addresses – so remove the `&` from the arguments in your `printf` calls. (Also, and I assume it's a typo, the `price[3]` expression should be `price[i]` – the former attempts to access an out-of-bounds element of the `price` array.)

Another issue is that, in each of your input loops, you call the `scanf` function *before* you display the relevant prompt. In the code below, I have reversed your `printf` and `scanf` lines in each of those input loops.

Here's a possible fixed version:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char name[3];
    float price[3];
    int i, page[3];
    printf("enter the name price and book\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("enter character:\n");
        scanf(" %c", &name[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("enter floating point number:\n");
        scanf("%f", &price[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("enter digit:\n");
        scanf("%d", &page[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("%c\n", name[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("%f\n", price[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", page[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i had another doubt in the concept of pointers , that is  an array of 5 elements  A[5]={1,2,3,4,5} and now we assign the value of first element in pointer *p=a,  then what is the value of *(a+0) , *(a+1)  and *p i didnt understand the difference between them please clarify this.

Comment: @user17725027 If `p` points to the first element of `a` then `*(p+i)` is the same as `a[i]`. In fact, the C Standard even says that the array indexing expression is equivalent to the pointer addition one.

Comment: Its clear thank you

Comment: i was trying to write a code for printing of last word from a sentence , we should take input of a sentence and print last word in it without using any library functions in C  except scanf and printf. if possible please give me a source code that will helps me.